# convert verilog to aiger with Yosys

Tags: verilog, yosys

I have several verilog files which I want to convert to aiger format using Yosys, I use the following commmad in yosys:

```
read_verilog gclk_reg.v nld_and.v my_ff_W_8_.v gated_netlist.v

synth_xilinx -flatten -top gclk_reg

aigmap

write_aiger -ascii my.aag
```

When I use the aigmap command, it show that cells like:

> VCC LUT2 GND LDCE

cannot be replaced.

Unsurprisingly, the write_aiger command fails, showing that:

> "ERROR: Unsupported cell type: VCC (VCC)".

So how can I map those cells to allowed cells of write_aiger?(I also used the abc -g AND command but it still failed)

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `synth` instead of `synth_xilinx`. This will map to a set of Yosys-internal gates that aigmap understands, rather than to a set of Xilinx primitives.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have tried synth command before, but it remaind that files like VCC.v LDCE.v .etc are missing, so how can I add such verilog library in the synth command?

Comment: You can try `read_verilog +/xilinx/cells_sim.v` before `synth`. I'm not sure if your downstream tool will be happy with latches in a netlist, though